# Use derived class's static method as function callback in C++

Tags: c++

I need to pass an object's static method as callback function using following code:

```
glutDisplayFunc(callback)
```

Where `callback` is a static method of some class - `baseClass::callback()`. It compiles fine. But now I want to have a derived class *(having `baseClass` as it's parent)* having the same callback function - that is, I want to overwrite the callback function.

I've overwritten it in derivedClass but `derivedClass::callback()` is not getting called.

PS. I'm calling `glutDisplayFunc(callback)` withing the base class. Code looks like:

```
baseClass::someFunction(){
    glutDisplayFunc(callback);
}
```

How do I pass `derivedClass::callback` instead of `baseClass::callback` withing a method of `baseClass?` All methods are static.

Comment: FWIW overriding a member function is only available for virtual functions, and static member functions can't be virtual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not support virtual static methods, so you can't do what you're trying to do directly. What you should be able to do is create a non-static virtual method that returns a function pointer, and override that in your derived class to return a pointer to it's static callback method.

i.e. something like this:

```
class A
{
public:
   typedef void(*CallbackFunction)(void);

public:
   static void callback(void)
   {
      std::cout << "A::callback" << std::endl;
   }

   virtual CallbackFunction getCallback()
   {
      return callback;
   }

   void someFunction()
   {
      glutDisplayFunc(getCallback());
   }

};

class B: public A
{
public:
   static void callback(void)
   {
      std::cout << "B::callback" << std::endl;
   }
   CallbackFunction getCallback()
   {
      return callback;
   }
};
```

Not exactly ideal, but it's a decent workaround for C callbacks that don't support context parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't, and furthermore you generally don't want to. A base class generally shouldn't have direct knowledge of specific derived functions.

The usual pattern for this is to have a static function in the base class that invokes a virtual function, then override the virtual function in the derived class. I'm not sure if that applies here though -- to work, you need to be able to get a parameter passed to the callback function. The parameter you pass is a pointer to the object, so you cast that back to the base object type, then invoke the correct virtual function off of that pointer.

In the specific case of glutDisplayFunc, however, I don't believe that's possible -- it doesn't allow you to get a parameter passed to the callback function. I'm afraid there is no real cure other than to switch to something other than GLUT if you want to do this style of programming.